# Understanding the definition of exact and short exact sequences and the proper terminiologies of its various components.

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, definition

Can someone tell me if my understanding of the term exact and short exact sequences are correct along with the correct terminology for the various part of the criterias in $(1), (2)$ and $(3)$ for short exact sequence.

$\textbf{Definition from beginning of Wikipedia entry}$

In the wikipedia entry on exact sequence, at the beginning, it states that ["An exact sequence is a sequence of morphisms between objects (for example, groups, rings, modules, and, more generally, objects of an abelian category) such that the image of one morphism equals the kernel of the next"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence)

My understanding of the definition:

Given algebraic objects $H$, $G$ and $K$ of the same type, be they: groups, vector spaces, rings, modules, etc, and pair of maps $g_{i-1}:H\rightarrow G$ and $g_{i}:G\rightarrow K$.  If both $g_{i-1}, g_{i}$ are $\textit{homomorphic}$ maps and $\text{Im }g_{i-1} = \text{Ker }g_{i}$.  Then such pair sequence of maps is called an $\textbf{exact sequence}$.  Also if there are more two maps in the sequence, than each of the maps have to be a homomorphism. Also, each pair of adjacent maps $g_{i-1}, g_{i}$, $\text{Im }g_{i-1} = \text{Ker }g_{i}$ for all $i\in \mathbb{Z}$, meaning the entire sequence of maps will be exact at each group.  [Section 22.3c pg 598,](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/The_Geometry_of_Physics/gXvHCiUlCgUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=The+Geometry+of+Physics:+An+Introduction.+exact+sequence&pg=PA598&printsec=frontcover)  [Section 22.3c pg 599](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/The_Geometry_of_Physics/gXvHCiUlCgUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=The+Geometry+of+Physics:+An+Introduction.+exact+sequence&pg=PA598&printsec=frontcover)<

> $\ldots\stackrel{\rm }{\longrightarrow}H\stackrel{\rm g_{i-1}}{\longrightarrow}G\stackrel{\rm g_{i}}{\longrightarrow}K\stackrel{\rm }{\longrightarrow}\dots$

For the case of $\textbf{short exact sequence}$ of the form below in the indentation:

> $\{0\}\stackrel{\rm f_{i-1}}{\longrightarrow}A\stackrel{\rm f_{i}}{\longrightarrow}B\stackrel{\rm f_{i+1}}{\longrightarrow}C\stackrel{\rm f_{i+2}}{\longrightarrow}\{0\}$

The conditions for such sequence of maps to be considered a short exact sequence, where $f_{i+2}$ is understood to be the zero map, [Definition 2.22](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Y8bcBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA26&dq=inclusion+map,+one+to+one,+exact+sequence&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&ovdme=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi1y_HFpdL5AhUiFmIAHVpfBOY4ChDoAXoECAgQAw#v=onepage&q=inclusion%20map%2C%20one%20to%20one%2C%20exact%20sequence&f=false) and the element $\{0\}$ denoting the identity.

$\textbf{Terminologies used for various maps in a short exact sequence}$

They are:

for any pair of adjacent maps, $f_{i}$ and $f_{i+1}$ in the sequence,

$(1)$ $f_{i}$ is an injective [Definition 2.22](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Y8bcBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA26&dq=inclusion+map,+one+to+one,+exact+sequence&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&ovdme=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi1y_HFpdL5AhUiFmIAHVpfBOY4ChDoAXoECAgQAw#v=onepage&q=inclusion%20map%2C%20one%20to%20one%2C%20exact%20sequence&f=false) and an inclusion [Section 1.11 second paragraph pg 79](https://books.google.ca/books?id=JFEyDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA79&dq=inclusion+map,+one+to+one,+exact+sequence&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&ovdme=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ1KSvpNL5AhXAEmIAHYcuBTkQ6AF6BAgMEAM#v=onepage&q=inclusion%20map%2C%20one%20to%20one%2C%20exact%20sequence&f=false) [paragraph before Theorem 1.2 pg 5](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Manifolds_Tensors_and_Forms/hbLCAQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Manifolds,+Tensors+and+Forms,+exact+sequences&pg=PA5&printsec=frontcover) map
$(2)$ $\text{Im }f_{i-1} = \text{Ker }f_{i}$
$(3)$ $f_{i+1}$ is a surjective [Definition 2.22](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Y8bcBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA26&dq=inclusion+map,+one+to+one,+exact+sequence&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&ovdme=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi1y_HFpdL5AhUiFmIAHVpfBOY4ChDoAXoECAgQAw#v=onepage&q=inclusion%20map%2C%20one%20to%20one%2C%20exact%20sequence&f=false)
 and a projection [Section 1.11 second paragraph pg 79](https://books.google.ca/books?id=JFEyDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA79&dq=inclusion+map,+one+to+one,+exact+sequence&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&ovdme=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ1KSvpNL5AhXAEmIAHYcuBTkQ6AF6BAgMEAM#v=onepage&q=inclusion%20map%2C%20one%20to%20one%2C%20exact%20sequence&f=false) map.

The reason for $(1)$ is because the map $f_{i-1}$ is an inclusion map [Theorem 9.7.1](https://books.google.ca/books?id=lBO7BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA387&dq=are+maps+in+a+short+exact+sequences+homomorphic+maps&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&ovdme=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjg_cLNjdv5AhXnjokEHTacCe04HhDoAXoECAUQAw#v=onepage&q=are%20maps%20in%20a%20short%20exact%20sequences%20homomorphic%20maps&f=false) which sends the zero element to $A$ and because it is a homomorphism where $f_{i-1}(0)=0$, and hence $\text{Im }f_{i-1} = \{0\}$.  Because of $(2)$ $\text{Im }f_{i-1} = \text{Ker }f_{i}$, so $\text{Ker }f_{i}=\{0\}$, and $f_{i}$ is an injective map.

For $(3)$, because the map $f_{i+2}$ sends every elements in $C$ to $0$, then $\text{Ker }f_{i+2}=C$ and because $\text{Im }f_{i+1} = \text{Ker }g_{i+2}=C$, this implies that $f_{i+1}$ is a surjective map.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask as question (0) if one can make sense of exact sequences for any `algebraic objects', and list (lets say commutative) rings as an example - no, not for commutative rings, since for example one doesn't have kernel rings (the kernels of ring morphisms are ideals). For groups, and $R$-modules (which includes vector spaces, where $R$ is taken to be a field in that case). Also, as mentioned in your other post (which I include for completeness sake), one simply calls a map in a specific category a morphism, or homomorphism.

(1) If you have an exact sequence, say of $R$-modules, $0\stackrel{a}\to M\stackrel{f}\to N\stackrel{g}\to K\stackrel{b}\to 0$, then note that $a$ is just including the zero element into $M$, and $b$ maps everything to zero. In particular, by the exactness of this sequence, $\{0\}=\text{im}(a)=\text{ker}(f)$, and this precisely tells you that for $m\in M$, $f(m)=0$ only if $m=0$, which is exactly what it means for $f$ to be injective. Similarly, $\text{im}(g)=\text{ker}(b)=K$, which means for every element $k\in K$, there is some element $n\in N$ for which $g(n)=k$, which is exactly what it means for $g$ to be surjective.

(2), (3), yes that's correct. I will say its somewhat strange to denote the arrows with such subscripts, as in your question, when you aren't considering long exact sequences.