# Question about the term "morphism" in exact and short exact ssequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, exact-sequence

I would like to know, in the context of exact sequences or short exact sequence:

> $\ldots\stackrel{\rm }{\longrightarrow}H\stackrel{\rm g_{i-1}}{\longrightarrow}G\stackrel{\rm g_{i}}{\longrightarrow}K\stackrel{\rm }{\longrightarrow}\dots$

where $\text{Im }g_{i-1} = \text{Ker }g_{i}$.  the term  "morphism" as in "R-morphism" for modules, or group homo-morphisms for groups is always used instead of simply "maps" between algebraic objects of the same types for the sequence of arrows.  Do the term "morphism" always mean homomorphism.  I see it in math subjects where exact sequences make an appearance.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One uses the term `morphism' to mean a map which is defined between two objects of a given [category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics)). In the context you are talking about (homological algebra), one is usually working in an [abelian category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_category).

Morphisms in the category of groups are called group homomorphisms. In the category of $R$-modules, morphisms are called $R$-linear maps. In the category of topological spaces, the morphisms are called continuous maps. In the category of sets, the morphisms are the set maps.

Comment: in the context of continuous map for topology, it doesn't have to preserve any kind of structure, or is the structure being preserve is homeomorphism?

Comment: @SethMai A continuous map does preserve structure: namely the preimage of each open set is an open set. Homeomorphisms are an example of the notion of an isomorphism in a category. An isomorphism of sets is called a bijection, an isomorphism of topological spaces is called a homeomorphism, an isomorphism of groups is called a group isomorphism. 

Just like a group homomorphism does not need to be an isomorphism, an a set map need not be a bijection, a continuous map need not be a homeomorphism. Note that an isomorphism in a category is a morphism in that category with a two-sided inverse.

Comment: I did not know that continuous map preserve structure, also thank you for providing a detail comment for my other question here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4517762/understanding-the-definition-of-exact-and-short-exact-sequences-and-the-proper-t/4518431#4518431

I keep seeing the word "morphism" in the context of exact sequence, wikipedia is equally not clear about the part about continuous map.  I thought the structure preserving bit when it comes to topology has to do with homeomorphism and not continuous functions.

Comment: also in a typical topology text, continuous map are not mentioned as structure preserving rather, it talks about preserving topological properties by making sure two topological spaces are homemomorphic.

Comment: Group homomorphisms are 'structure preserving' because they 'respect the group operation', even if they aren't isomorphisms. For example the quotient map from the integers $(\Bbb Z, +)\to (Z/n\Bbb Z,+)$ is structure preserving on additive groups, since it respects the addition. The morphism of rings $(\Bbb Z,+,\times)\to (\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z,+,\times)$ is structure preserving because it respects both the addition operation, and the multiplication operation. If you think about continuous maps between topological spaces with metric topologies, it might be clearer why this is 'structure preserving'.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification, for continuous functions in a non metric space contexts, the structure preserving there would mean the function sends open sets to open sets?

Comment: @SethMai Recall that a topological space $X$ has two parts to it, where the second is usually suppressed, namely $(X,\tau_X)$. A morphism in the category of topological spaces $f:(X,\tau_X)\to (Y,\tau_Y)$ is a map of sets $f:X\to Y$ with the additional property (which is the part that makes one call it 'structure preserving') that for any open $U\in \tau_Y$ (recalling that $U\subseteq Y$) the preimage of sets $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$, i.e. $f^{-1}(U)\in \tau_X$. One can think of a continuous map as giving a map $\tau_Y\to \tau_X$ if they wish, which is taking opens to their preimage.

Comment: ah kk.  Thank you for clarification.  I am typing up a more detail comment to clarifying what I am confused about for the other question.